# Is there a single word to say "modify with an adjective"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Adjectivize means to turn into an adjective, but is there a single word you can use to describe modifying a noun with an adjective?

Comment: Do an adjective [**qualify⁴**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/qualify) the noun?

Comment: Not a single word, but we typically say 'adjectival modification'.

Comment: @Weather Vane possibly as close as it gets, but this works for other adjectivals (a bore _of the first water_). 'Epithetise' means 'characterise', addressing the referent rather than the noun.

Comment: "Qualify" doesn't specify the category of the dependent . In any case, it's just another term for the more commonly used 'modifier'.

Comment: You are looking for an intransitive verb? I don't think there is one that means *modify a noun*. *Modify* works just fine if you can use a transitive verb.

Comment: No, there is no such word, just as there is no special word for modifying a verb with an adverb, or an adjective with an adverb, or a noun with an article. Each of these involves a relation (_modify_, not the simplest concept) and two distinct entities in that relation. No language can handle this much diversity by giving every possible combination a single word. This is what noun phrases are for.